# How can I automatically download and archive my own YouTube videos?

Tags: bash, backup, python

I want to download all my YouTube videos (potentially hundreds or thousands, including live streams).
I have MANY private YouTube videos that are really for my own personal usage.
I am beginning to trust Google less and less and would like a local, hard backup of all my videos.

Unfortunately, Google Takeout has been failing for some unknown reason.  I even paid for a Dropbox account with unlimited storage and the "Save to Dropbox" feature was failing without any error messages.
They have the option to download them by clicking the links manually, but that is completely horrible because there are THOUSANDS of zip files.  I am not going to click each and every single zip file.  Furthermore, I tried to write a short script to automatically click each link, but Google is not only throttling me, but the Angular application they use opens and closes the dialog and messes up the whole flow.

I would really appreciate somebody showing me how I can possibly back up all my data from Google without using their horrifically broken Google Takeout process.

Answer (score 2):

If you can somehow generate a list of URLs for the content you may use `youtube-dl`.

One way might be: create a 'playlist' (on youtube) with all your videos and then use the `--playlist-items` option to get them downloaded.

Otherwise with a list of URLs:

```
$ cat url-list |  \
while read url ; do 
  echo -e "\n$(tput rev) --- $url --- $(tput sgr0)"; 
  echo youtube-dl "$url";
done
```

*remove `echo` just before youtube-dl as you're ready to actually run it*

Answer (score 2):

Use [`youtube-dl`](https://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/index.html) to do so:

1. Once [downloaded](https://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html), add the YouTube playlist link to `youtube-dl-channels.txt`:

   - **Download all videos from a channel:** 
      Link will be `https://www.youtube.com/channel/` followed by channel's unique ID 
      *(e.g. `https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC4FiN46mPTtkJxzRXJY21lQ`)*
   - **Download a channel's specific playlist:** 
      Link will be `https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=` followed by playlist's unique ID 
      *(e.g. `https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLmybwiwzi3MUAwm6BuEg3SOlBeaQosHNu`)*
2. Configure the [options](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#options) you want in `youtube-dl.conf` *(I use the following)*:

   ```bsh
   #

             ##::[[---  youtube-dl Config  ---]]::##

   #===========================================================
                     ##----- Global -----##
   #===========================================================

     ## https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#options

   # Options:
   #-----------------------------------------------------------

   # Continue on download errors:
   -i


   # Video Selection:
   #-----------------------------------------------------------

   # Archive Settings (outputs each video's youtu.be URL ID):
   --download-archive youtube-dl-archive.txt


   # Filesystem:
   #-----------------------------------------------------------

   # Filename Template:
   -o "%(uploader)s/%(playlist)s/%(playlist_index)s - %(title)s (%(duration)ss on %(upload_date)s @ %(id)s).%(ext)s"

   # Force resume of partially downloaded files:
   -c

   # Write video description to a .description file:
   --write-description

   # Write video metadata to a .info.json file:
   --write-info-json

   # Write video annotations to a .annotations.xml file:
   --write-annotations


   # Thumbnail Images:
   #-----------------------------------------------------------

   # Write thumbnail image to disk:
   --write-thumbnail


   # Verbosity:
   #-----------------------------------------------------------

   # Print various debugging information:
   -v


   # Video Format:
   #-----------------------------------------------------------

   # Video format:
   -f ("bestvideo[width>=1920]"/bestvideo)+bestaudio/best

   # Output to given format if merge is required:
   --merge-output-format mkv


   # Subtitle:
   #-----------------------------------------------------------

   # Write automatically generated subtitle file:
   --write-auto-sub

   # Language:
   --sub-lang en


   # Post-processing:
   #-----------------------------------------------------------

   # Write metadata to the video file:
   --add-metadata

   # Prefer ffmpeg over avconv:
   --prefer-ffmpeg

   # Convert subtitles to specififed format:
   --convert-subs srt
   ```
3. **Execute directly:**

   ```bsh
   youtube-dl --config-location youtube-dl.conf
   ```

   **Execute via script:**

   ```bsh
   echo "#!/bin/sh

   youtube-dl --config-location youtube-dl.conf" > download_archive.sh

   chmod +x ./download_archive.sh ; ./download_archive.sh
   ```